# What other ways can python look for modules?

Tags: python, python-import, arcpy

We have a software called ArcGIS that comes with a python environment, which has a library called `arcpy`

When you execute the python.exe from that environment, it imports `arcpy` with no issue.

But I needed to create another python enviroment that contains the same library as this one, but I just couldn't find anything named `arcpy` in the enviroment's folders

I even copied the whole `Lib` folder from the original enviroment to the one I'm trying to create, but it still won't `import arcpy`

I know this is kinda of a shot in the dark, as it is a proprietary library and I can't be sharing much info, but does anyone knows what could it be?

It seems they use Anaconda too

Comment: Most likely they are setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH to point to the directory where arcpy lives. Some more environment variables are listed here. https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

Comment: @Ron both have the same PYTHONPATH, I'm afraid that's not it

Comment: Try opening the python prompt and do `import sys` then `sys.path`. It'll return a list of the paths where its looking for python modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python (arcpy) install with ArcGIS typicall installs to:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5
```

Arcpy does ***not*** like to be moved, and the library is linked directly with your ArcGIS installation

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5
```

If you are using ArcGIS Pro rather than Desktop, it installs into Conda environment:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\
```

This Q&A on [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) may be of some interest to you - [How to set up Python/ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro 1.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203380/how-to-set-up-python-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

Go inside the environment with arcpy, look for the environment var PYTHON_PATH. and just add that path to the PYTHON_PATH in your new environment.

Comment: I used `os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')` in both envs and both pointed to the same folder